# C#: Simple state machine, how to get state from database and assing it?

Tags: c#

I am wondering how to assign a loaded state from a database to a state machine.

Simple example IState interface:

```
public interface IState
{
    void Process(MyClass obj);
}
```

We got 3 possible states: New, Modified and Finished:

```
public class StateNew : IState
{
    public void Process(MyClass obj)
    {
        // processing stuff
        obj.State = new StateModified();
    }
}

public class StateModified : IState
{
    public void Process(MyClass obj)
    {
        // processing stuff
        obj.State = new StateFinished();
    }
}

public class StateFinished : IState
{
    public void Process(MyClass obj)
    {
        // processing stuff
    }
}
```

Then, our class:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private IState _state;
    public IState State
    {
            get { return _state; }
            set
            {
                _state = value;
            }
    }

    public MyClass()
    {
        _state = new StateNew();
    }

    public void Process() => State.Process(this);
}
```

So, we deal with the class and then, we save it to the database saving in the "state field" the value "xxx.StateModified" that `_state.ToString()` provided us.

The show must go on so the moment of loading the object from the database has arrived, and the database says that state field is `xxx.StateModified`.

In 2022, with C# v10 available and C# v11 incoming, there has to be a better approach to this that making up a constructor with a switch:

```
public MyClass(string? stateName = "StateNew")
{
        switch (stateName)
        {
            case "StateModified":
                State = new StateModified();
                break;

            case "StateFinished":
                State = new StateFinished();
                break;

            default:
                State = new StateNew();
                break;
        }
}
```

:(((((

Comment: I think I would use a separate entity in the database that holds the possible states and assign the id of the desired state to the object.

Comment: You could also use an `enum` with fixed values and assign that to the `State`. Is a little less flexible but faster.

Comment: But I don't want to use an enum becasue then states will be hardcoded.

Comment: You should ask yourself. Are my statusses going to change very often? If not go for the `enum` if true than go for the extra `entity`. Hardcoded is in itself not bad practice but should be avoided for data that may change frequently.